# Rename Prestashop mobile menu caption

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I use PrestaShop 1.6.0.9. I know how to change the items in the top navigation menu or how to add/delete categories from the left menu.

But I can't investigate how to change the **caption of category menu in mobile template**?

You can see [here](http://vonaveauto.cz) that the left category menu on desktop is called "Produkty". If you scale down the tab or you view it on your mobile, it is called "Menu". I would like to rename it. I tried to find it in the Localization / Translation of the template, core and moduls. Unfortunatelly without any success.

Do you know which files should be edited to display "Menu" caption as "Produkty" even on the mobile?

Comment: You should have a look in your theme template files. Search for this module template file and you might find that it's not using translation.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I tried to find anything with label "menu" through ftp and it found just a lot of css files or php/tpl files where any "menu" could be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

It was located in files in www/modules/tmleftmenu/ and need to be replaced in in files:

- tmleftmenu.tpl (for mobile view)
- tmleftmenu_left.tpl (for desktop
  view)